# How can I create a custom TabBar in a MAUI app?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I want to create a custom TabBar in a MAUI app (Android and Windows). I want the upper edges to be rounded and ading some other customizations. What I've tried:

- The shell's TabBar control is not customisable at all... I was
  experimenting with a shell custom renderer but I am not really sure
  how I could achive a custom look in MAUI and how to implement it.
- Instead of using the shell's TabBar I created a custom TabBar which derives from the ContentView class and with a TapGestureRecogniser I navigated to a new page when an image was clicked. And I used this custom control in every page at the bottom. But it resulted in a flickering transition when I navigated to a diffrent page. And it looks weird that the TabBar flickers during the navigation.

What other ways are there to achieve a custom look? Or what do I miss in my previous attempts?

Comment: Try to put it inside [Border](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border)

Comment: It's already inside a border. But when I navigate to other page the whole page flickers once including my custom TabBar.

Comment: @Rena821 May I know on which platform you are targeting to customize the [Tabar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#bottom-tabs) appearance?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, I am mainly targeting android and windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add functionality or change behavior's take some researching but it is very rewarding. That is what we do, bend code to our will. The only thing to think about is that it is maintainable and testable. Otherwise go crazy, and make amazing things.

Normally you use Handlers for this, that is always your number one choice, but in the case of TabBar there is no Handler so you need to go with Renders, the old way of Xamarin.Forms. I will give you some starter pointer in code so you can test and find your way through this.

First you need to understand a little about [renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers). So we need to use the `ShellRenderer` for this, because it is here you find the [TabBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs)

So let us derive from `ShellRenderer`. If we look inside `ShellRenderer` we find that there is a method that look like something
we want and can override:

```cs
protected virtual IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem);
```

So let us make our new Renderer by adding a new file to the Android platform and start there (you will need to make such file on every platform).

```cs
partial class ShellHandlerEx : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTrackerEx(this, shellItem.CurrentItem);
    }
}
```

As you see from the code and the return type, we will need to add another file that do the actual change to the `TabBar` and that derives from `IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker`:

```cs
class ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTrackerEx : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    private readonly IShellContext shellContext;

    public ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTrackerEx(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem) : base(shellContext, shellItem)
    {
        this.shellContext = shellContext;
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
        var backgroundDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        backgroundDrawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
        backgroundDrawable.SetCornerRadii(new float[] { 30, 30, 30, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        bottomView.SetBackground(backgroundDrawable); 
    }
}
```

If we look at the `ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` we see that there is a method we can overrid called `SetAppearance`. Here we get `BottomNavigationView` and when looking inside that one we find `SetBackground`, that takes a `Drawable`. So we read about drawables on Android and make a drawable and fix the corners and you have your `TabBar` with nice round corners at the top.

The last thing we need to do is to register this with our app. As always we do that in `MauiProgram.cs` in our Builder.

```cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
    {
         handlers.AddHandler<Shell, ShellHandlerEx>();
    });
```

Now you need to do this on all platforms you want this to support. Still you need to make a dummy to those platforms you dont support.

I hope this tutorial helps.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a custom TabBar which derives from the ContentView class

First: This is not a TabBar, this is plain and simple custom control. You can easily replace the word TabBar with the word Button in your question, and it will carry exactly the same information.

> And I used this custom control in every page at the bottom

Second: This is your problem. You create and use it at **every page**.
This is not a single control, it is a bunch of controls, that get constructed, drawn, destructed etc.

> And it looks weird that the TabBar flickers during the navigation.

Third: This is the result of redrawing it over and over. To be honest, flickering will be the least of your problems if you want to make your tabbar like that.

The task to rewrite TabBar is not easy one. As you can see from the MAUI implementation, it has complex structure, with different types of object, nested as lists into each other.

I have used BindableLayout for something simple as 2-3 tabs, but that is it. Beyond that, if you want your whole application to be designed based on it, you  will need a whole team to rewrite it and deal with bugs.

What I am trying to say is - use what the platform provides to you. And customize it as much as you can, given the tools of the platform.