# How can I make custom tabbed page in MAUI?

Tags: maui, handler, uitabbar, bottomnavigationview, tabbedpage

I created a tabbed page, and I am trying to achieve this kind of Bottom Tab Bar.
[image]

I manage to do this in ***Android*** using [TabbedViewHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.handlers.tabbedviewhandler?view=net-maui-7.0), but there is an unwanted white layer behind the custom tab bar, how can I remove this? **and also I couldn't found a similar solution for iOS**.

[image]

I tried this for Android:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using System.Reflection;
#if ANDROID
using static Android.Views.ViewGroup;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using AndroidX.Core.View;
#endif

namespace Project.Views.Handlers
{
    public class AndroidTabbedPageHandler : TabbedViewHandler
    {
        public AndroidTabbedPageHandler()
        {
            Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(CustomTabbedPage), (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                if (view is CustomTabbedPage)
                {
                    FieldInfo tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo = typeof(TabbedPage).GetField("_tabbedPageManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    object tabbedPageManager = tabbedPageManagerFieldInfo?.GetValue(view);

                    FieldInfo tabLayoutFieldInfo = tabbedPageManager?.GetType().GetField("_bottomNavigationView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = tabLayoutFieldInfo?.GetValue(tabbedPageManager) as BottomNavigationView;

                    if (bottomNavigationView != null)
                    {
                        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
                        drawable.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
                        drawable.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                        drawable.SetCornerRadius(40);
                        MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = new(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                        layoutParams.SetMargins(20, 0, 20, 40);
                        bottomNavigationView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                        bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
                        bottomNavigationView.SetElevation(12);
                        ViewCompat.SetBackground(bottomNavigationView, drawable);
                    }
                }
#endif
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the TabbedViewHandler you inherited the same as the [TabbedViewHandle](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Handlers/TabbedView/TabbedViewHandler.cs)? [Creating a custom handler requires a property mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create#create-the-property-mapper), could you please provide relevant code so that I can test?

Comment: Try this i guess https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS, please refer to [the TabbarRenderer source code in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Compatibility/Handlers/TabbedPage/iOS/TabbedRenderer.cs#L20C1-L20C1) ,the TabbedPage is implemented by `TabbedRenderer` on iOS platform, so you can try to create a new Renderer class and let it inherit `TabbedRenderer`.

Specifically, you can change the position and angle of the Tabbar by override the iOS native method named `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` like the following code.

```
    public class CustomTabbar : TabbedRenderer
    {
#if iOS
        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            Tabbar.Layer.CornerRadius = 40;
            Tabbar.Layer.MasksToBounds = True;
            TabBar.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X + 10, TabBar.Frame.Y - 20, TabBar.Frame.Width - 20, TabBar.Frame.Height + 5);
        }
#end if
    }
```